Blender move cube using shortcut is dragging around other unselected objects as well
So I try to use the G shortcut to move the cube with X, Y and Z. It looks like my settings got messed somehow and now the cube moves with itself some elements in the scene. What setting did I mess up?
https://i.imgur.com/fsKeuDb.gif

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

This looks like Proportional Editing possibly, but is this your file or could someone else have added drivers to the stair steps' location transforms?

@TheLabCat that was it, thank you!
